# Result of urdu ontology in jsp

Tags: jsp, sparql, ontology, urdu

I'm new to sparql. I'm trying to retrieve Urdu results from the sparql query and code is working fine in Java forms but when I try to print the result in jsp it shows "ا�? ر_ب�" like this.

```java
 String novelname=request.getParameter("Id");
             novelname = novelname.replaceAll("\\s","");
              OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF);
FileManager.get().readModel( model, "C:/Users/Bisma/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Novelmania/web/novelname.owl" );
       String queryStrings ="prefix uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/novelname.owl#>" +
"select * {uni:"+novelname+" uni:translate ?Novelname. }"; 
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryStrings);
QueryExecution qe= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet resultset = qe.execSelect();
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos= new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ResultSetFormatter.outputAsCSV(baos, resultset);
            String answer= new String(baos.toString().getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF-8");

            answer= java.util.Arrays.toString(answer.split("http://www.semanticweb.org/novelname.owl#"));
String[]  arrays = answer.split(",");
String nam=arrays[1];
nam=nam.substring(0, nam.length()-1);
nam=nam.replaceAll("\\s","");
out.print(nam);
```

? �?" something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code sample is a bit messy, so it's hard to see *exactly* what is going wrong, but I think that part of the problem is that you are incorrectly decoding the Urdu characters:

```java
String answer = new String(baos.toString().getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF-8");
```

So, you have a `ByteArrayOutputStream` on which you call `toString`, which decodes the byte array into a character string using the default platform encoding - this will only work correctly if the byte array was also produced using the default platform encoding. If that is not the case, you should be explicit which encoding you want to use: `toString(charsetname`).

On the string you just produced you then call `getBytes("ISO8859_1")` - so you are converting the string you just created *back* into bytes, using ISO-8859-1 encoding. Apart from the fact that `"ISO8859_1"` is not the correct character set name to use (it should be `"ISO-8859-1"`, or better yet, use the `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` constant), this just is wrong. ISO-8859-1 is an encoding for the basic Latin alphabet, so it is almost certainly not suitable for Urdu.

Then, finally, you convert this second byte array back into a `String` again, but this time you use the `UTF-8` charset encoding. This is certainly incorrect, since you just produced that byte array using a different encoding, so you *know* it's not UTF-8!

In short, it's a mess. I think all you really need to do is this:

```java
String answer = baos.toString(charsetName);
```

...and then figure out what `charsetName` should be, that is, which character set encoding was used to create the byte array.